# Rbind multiple Data Frames in a loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a bunch of data frames that are named in the same pattern "dfX.csv" where X represents a number from 1 to 67. I loaded them into seperate dataframes using following piece of code:

```
folder <- mypath
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv") 
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  assign(file_list[i],      
  read.csv(paste(folder, file_list[i], sep=',', header=TRUE))     
)}
```

What I'm trying to do is merge/rbind them into a single huge dataframe.

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
df_main <- rbind(df_main, df[[i]].csv)
}
```

However using that I'm getting an error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
    df_main <- rbind(df_main, df[[i]].csv"
```

Any idea what might be causing an issue & whether there's a simpler way of doing things.

Comment: You should never ever ever iteratively `rbind` within a loop: performance might be okay in the beginning, but with each call to `rbind` it makes a complete copy of the data, so with each pass the total data to copy increases. It scales horribly. Consider `do.call(rbind.data.frame, file_list)`.

Comment: Ahhhh ... but `df[[i]].csv` is not valid R code. If `df` is at this point a filename, then perhaps you should read it in first (e.g., `read.csv`) into a frame and then deal with it? Perhaps `frame_list <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)` and then `do.call(rbind.data.frame, frame_list)`.

Comment: Yes. dfX.csv is also a name of individual dataframes.

Comment: Added also piece of code used to load CSVs.

Comment: Side note: based on your "load-in" code, I think it'd be better to do `file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)` (last arg helps), then `alldat <- lapply(file_list, read.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",")`. (BTW, it looks like your arguments for `read.csv` are being passed to `paste` instead; check your parens.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `file_list` is a `character` vector of filenames that have since been loaded into variables in the local environment, then perhaps one of

```r
do.call(rbind.data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\s+\\.csv")))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, mget(paste0("df", seq_along(file_list), ".csv")))
```

The first assumes anything found (as `df*.csv`) in R's environment is appropriate to grab. It might not grab then in the correct order, so consider using `sort` or somehow ordering them yourself.

`mget` takes a string vector and retrieves the value of the object with each name from the given environment (current, by default), returning a list of values.

`do.call(rbind.data.frame, ...)` does *one* call to `rbind`, which is much much faster than iteratively `rbind`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Here I use `map()` to iterate over your files reading each one into a list of dataframes and `bind_rows` is used to bind all df together

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- map(list.files(), read_csv) %>%
bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data (lot of rows), here's a `data.table` approach that works great:

```
library(data.table)
basedir <- choose.dir() # directory with all the csv files

file_names <- list.files(path = basedir, pattern= '*.csv', full.names = F, recursive = F)

big_list <- lapply(file_names, function(file_name){
  dat <- fread(file = file.path(basedir, file_name), header = T)

  # Add a 'filename' column to each data.table to back-track where it was read from 
  # this is why we set full.names = F in the list.files line above 
  dat$filename <- gsub('.csv', '', file_name)
  return(dat)
})

big_data <- rbindlist(l = big_list, use.names = T, fill = T)
```

If you want to read only some columns and not all, you can use the `select` argument in `fread` - helps improve speed since empty columns are not read in, similarly `skip` lets you skip reading in a bunch of rows.